# How to send a http request in protractor JS after logging into site

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

So I basically found out the API endpoints of the Angular JS site I'm writing tests for are not exposed. And there are no documentation on how to hit those endpoints to manipulate the backend before I start the front end tests.

So, what I'm thinking is first log into the Angular site. Grab all headers and the cookie for that particular user.

Then send a crafted http request hitting the necessary endpoints before I start the test.

I don't know the best way to go about this. Has anyone done this before using Protractor JS?

I need some ideas how to proceed.

Comment: so I guess no one needs to do this ever...

Comment: maybe i don't understand your goal, but protractor is used to simulate a users behavior on a website. if you need mock data have a look [here](https://github.com/atecarlos/protractor-http-mock) or take a look at protractors beforAll method. hope i could help a bit